# How do I view a DLL's functions?

Tags: dll

There's a file that I got without an extension so I've opened it in a hex editor and saw this:

```
PK.........¬uJ[~"0...T......PassMasterExtension3_1.dll9c..|O/K
```

So what is that PK at the beginning of the file?

Comment: ` PK` try to rename it into a `.zip` file. Sounds like a zipped DLL.

Comment: Could you just open it with a hex editor and provide a line or 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the extension, you can be stuck, but lots of files have what is called a "magic number", a header helping programs (or people) to figure out of which type is the data.

may come handy when the contents is dumped over a socket for instance, or if the file is renamed to workaround antivirus programs in e-mail.

In your case: PK.........¬uJ¨[מ~"&...T......PassMasterExtension3_1.dll

`PK` looks very much like the magic number for a `.zip` file, and the fact that there's a filename after that reinforces that feeling.

I would rename the file to add the `.zip` extension, and see what happens when trying to open it using 7-zip or Winzip.

(note that you have to trust the sender because the file could contain a virus and hasn't been scanned by the e-mail antivirus)

Comment: Yes, for all practical purposes